# Problem with scope while accesing groups with Facebook JS SDK

Tags: facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-group

I'm trying to get access to user's pages and groups. Im using JS SDK v17.0. I have no problems with accessing user's pages but i cannot access groups. Here's the code I use:

```
function getuserData (videoID){
            FB.login(function(wynik3) {
                if(wynik3.authResponse && wynik3.status === 'connected'){
                    userLogged = 1;
                    response = wynik3.authResponse;
                    readPagesGroups(videoID);
                }else{
                    myApp.showError( myApp.GetLabel('video_upload_facebook_login') );
                }
            },
            {scope:"pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_posts, publish_video, user_managed_groups"});
}

// Neither user_managed_groups nor publish_to_groups works

function readPagesGroups(videoID){
    FB.api('/me/accounts', function(wynik4) {
        pagesRead = 1 ;
        if(wynik4.data.length == 0 || wynik4.error){
          console.log('You dont have pages');
        }else{
            responsePage = wynik4.data;
            renderStructure(videoID);
        }
    });
    FB.api('/me/groups', { fields: 'id,name' } ,function(groups){
        groupsRead = 1 ;
        if(groups.data.length == 0 || groups.error){
            console.log('You dont have groups');
        }else{
          responseGroups = groups.data;
          console.log(responseGroups)
            renderStructure(videoID);
        }
    });
}
```

Application works fine untill I use 'user_managed_groups' or 'publish_to_groups' scopes. Then in login popup error shows saying "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."

First I thought that it was a problem with app review, but I have done all possible reviews of my app and this problem still exists. I know I have one group as an admin, and I need access to this group.